# Окрашивается полный круг вместо части (Qt Graphics View)

Tags: c++, qt

Пишу на Qt с использованием QGraphicsView. Цель в том что бы отоброжать круг по секторам, для этого есть массив   `QVector<QGraphicsEllipseItem*> sectors;`. Угол начала и конца сектора задается относительно того сколько всего секторов

```
auto start_angle = i * (360/this->Size() * 16);
auto end_angle = start_angle + (360/this->Size() *16);
this->sectors[i]->setStartAngle(start_angle);
this->sectors[i]->setSpanAngle(end_angle);
```

[image]

Вот так например выглядит 5 секторов без заливания цветом (почему 2 слиты это тоже надо выяснить)
Добавление сектора на сцену (form_rect - прямоугольник с размерами полного круга)

```
this->sectors.push_back(new QGraphicsEllipseItem(form_rect));
this->scene.addItem(this->sectors[this->Size()-1]);
```

Когда пытаюсь задать им цвет через setBrush

```
this->sectors[i]->setBrush(rgb(i/this->Size()));
```

Почему-то вечь круг заливает одним цветом (последним)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя поидее сектора должны быть разного цвета
**Проблема точно не в функции что возвращает цвет, вот при выводе этих цветов видно что цвета разные**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать что бы каждый сектор был своего цвета а весь круг одного?
Если проблема еще не решена с полным кодом можно ознакомиться на  https://github.com/A1b1on/What_To_Do_Application

Comment: Поверьте величины начального и конечного углов каждого сектора, которые Вы высчитали. Не уверен, но возможно - ошибка там

Comment: spanAngle считается от начального угла StartAngle. Вместо auto end_angle = start_angle + (360/this->Size() *16); напишите auto end_angle =  (360/this->Size() *16);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Угол сектора считается от startAngle.

```
auto end_angle =  360/this->Size() *16;
```

Comment: Спасибо заработало, это такие тонкости из документации?

Comment: Нет. Простая математика)